# SimpleITK cannot find the ITK functions in C++

Tags: c++, qt, itk, simpleitk

I have installed the simpleITK library according this tutorial https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/master/Documentation/docs/source/building.html#building-simpleitk. For that I used the SuperBuild section, which is basically the following commands:

```
git clone  https://itk.org/SimpleITK.git
mkdir SimpleITK-build
cd SimpleITK-build
cmake ../SimpleITK/SuperBuild

make -j2
```

I'm using the qt creator on UBUNTU 16.04 as the IDE for this project. I've included the include path for the ITK (ITK-prefix) and the SimpleITK (SimpleITK-Build) as well. I also included the libraries related with the include files, but my compiler returns the "undefined reference to " some functions that are in the ITK section (GaussianSource and Image) (In the end of the question I putted the messages).

So, what am I missing to include?

Here is my .pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

INCLUDEPATH += /home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/include/SimpleITK-1.3
INCLUDEPATH += /home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/include/ITK-4.13

#SimpleITK LIB files
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libgtest.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITKBasicFilters0-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITKCommon-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITKBasicFilters1-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITKExplicit-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITKIO-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKAnisotropicSmoothing-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKAntiAlias-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKBiasCorrection-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKBinaryMathematicalMorphology-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKClassifiers-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKColormap-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKCommon-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKConnectedComponents-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKConvolution-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKCurvatureFlow-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKDeconvolution-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKDenoising-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKDisplacementField-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKDistanceMap-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKFastMarching-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKFFT-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKImageCompare-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKImageCompose-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKImageFeature-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKImageFilterBase-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKImageFunction-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKImageFusion-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKImageGradient-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKImageGrid-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKImageIntensity-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKImageLabel-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKImageNoise-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKImageSources-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKImageStatistics-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKLabelMap-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKLabelVoting-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKLevelSets-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKMathematicalMorphology-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKPDEDeformableRegistration-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKRegionGrowing-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKRegistrationCommon-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKReview-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKSmoothing-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKThresholding-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKTransform-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_ITKWatersheds-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITKRegistration-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITK_SimpleITKFilters-1.3.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build/lib/libSimpleITKUnitTestBase.a"

#ITK Lib Files
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKBiasCorrection-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKBioCell-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKCommon-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKDICOMParser-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkdouble-conversion-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKEXPAT-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKFEM-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkgdcmcharls-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkgdcmCommon-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkgdcmDICT-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkgdcmDSED-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkgdcmIOD-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkgdcmjpeg8-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkgdcmjpeg12-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkgdcmjpeg16-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkgdcmMEXD-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkgdcmMSFF-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkgdcmopenjp2-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkgdcmsocketxx-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkgdcmuuid-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKgiftiio-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkhdf5.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkhdf5_cpp.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOBMP-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOBruker-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOCSV-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOGDCM-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOGE-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOGIPL-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOHDF5-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOImageBase-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOIPL-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOJPEG-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOLSM-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOMesh-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOMeta-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOMINC-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOMRC-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIONIFTI-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIONRRD-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOPNG-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOSiemens-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOSpatialObjects-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOStimulate-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOTIFF-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOTransformBase-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOTransformHDF5-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOTransformInsightLegacy-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOTransformMatlab-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKIOXML-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkjpeg-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKKLMRegionGrowing-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKLabelMap-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitklbfgs-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKMesh-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKMetaIO-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkminc2-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitknetlib-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkNetlibSlatec-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKniftiio-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKNrrdIO-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkopenjpeg-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKOptimizers-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKOptimizersv4-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKPath-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkpng-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKPolynomials-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKQuadEdgeMesh-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKReview-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKSpatialObjects-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKStatistics-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitksys-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitktestlib-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitktiff-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKTransform-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKTransformFactory-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkv3p_netlib-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkvcl-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKVideoCore-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKVideoIO-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkvnl-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkvnl_algo-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKVNLInstantiation-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKVTK-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKWatersheds-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libitkzlib-4.13.a"
LIBS += -L"/home/felippe/SimpleITK-build/ITK-prefix/lib/libITKznz-4.13.a"

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
```

And here is my code:

```
// This one header will include all SimpleITK filters and external
// objects.
#include "SimpleITK.h"
#include "sitkImageOperators.h"
#include "sitkImage.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


// create convenient namespace alias
namespace sitk = itk::simple;

int main () {

  sitk::PixelIDValueEnum pixelType = sitk::sitkUInt8;
  std::vector<unsigned int> imageSize ( 2, 128 );

  // Create an image
  itk::simple::Image image( imageSize, pixelType );

  // Create a face image
  std::vector<double> faceSize ( 2, 64.0 );
  std::vector<double> faceCenter ( 2, 64.0 );;
  sitk::Image face = sitk::GaussianSource( pixelType, imageSize, faceSize, faceCenter );

  // Create eye images
  std::vector<double> eyeSize ( 2, 5.0 );
  std::vector<double> eye1Center ( 2, 48.0 );
  std::vector<double> eye2Center;
  eye2Center.push_back( 80.0 );
  eye2Center.push_back( 48.0 );
  sitk::Image eye1 = sitk::GaussianSource( pixelType, imageSize, eyeSize, eye1Center, 150 );
  sitk::Image eye2 = sitk::GaussianSource( pixelType, imageSize, eyeSize, eye2Center, 150 );

  // Apply the eyes to the face
  face = face - eye1 - eye2;
  face = sitk::BinaryThreshold( face, 200, 255, 255 );

  // Create the mouth
  std::vector<double> mouthRadii;
  mouthRadii.push_back( 30.0 );
  mouthRadii.push_back( 20.0 );
  std::vector<double> mouthCenter;
  mouthCenter.push_back( 64.0 );
  mouthCenter.push_back( 76.0 );
  sitk::Image mouth = 255 - sitk::BinaryThreshold(
                              sitk::GaussianSource(pixelType, imageSize, mouthRadii, mouthCenter),
                              200, 255, 255 );

  // Paste the mouth onto the face
  std::vector<unsigned int> mouthSize;
  mouthSize.push_back( 64 );
  mouthSize.push_back( 18 );
  std::vector<int> mouthLoc;
  mouthLoc.push_back( 32 );
  mouthLoc.push_back( 76 );
  face = sitk::Paste( face, mouth, mouthSize, mouthLoc, mouthLoc );

  // Apply the face to the original image
  image = image + face;

  // Display the results
  sitk::Show( image, "Hello World: C++", true );

}
```

Here is the errors messages:

```
/home/felippe/Área de Trabalho/Felippe/Mestrado/C_plus_plus/Codigos/RegistrationITK/main.cpp:33: error: undefined reference to `itk::simple::GaussianSource(itk::simple::PixelIDValueEnum, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > const&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&, double, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, bool)'

/home/felippe/Área de Trabalho/Felippe/Mestrado/C_plus_plus/Codigos/RegistrationITK/main.cpp:36: error: undefined reference to `itk::simple::Image::operator=(itk::simple::Image const&)'

/home/felippe/Área de Trabalho/Felippe/Mestrado/C_plus_plus/Codigos/RegistrationITK/main.cpp:63: error: undefined reference to `itk::simple::Show(itk::simple::Image const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
```

Thanks.

Comment: I've included the cmakelists. I didn't included the .pro because the forum limited the amount of characters. But if necessary I can include as an answer.

Comment: I've included an answer with my .pro and the code.

Comment: Please be a little more specific than “some functions”. The name of the function and the exact error message will likely be helpful.

Comment: I've included these messages.

Comment: I don't think you need to include any of the ITK stuff, since you're just using SimpleITK.  Those missing items should be in libSimpleITKCommon and libSimpleITKIO.  Could you try using CMake to build your code?

Comment: Dave, I included these libraries but when I've done this, the compiler returns the "undefined reference" messages with itk functions. I could try compiling this using cmake, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Dave, I've tried to compile using CMake, but I'm getting some errors. It said to me that it can't find the FindItk.cmake in the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH. So cmake asked for " Add the installation prefix of "ITK" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "ITK_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files (ITKConfig.cmake)." 

But I actually did this (I set both variables (not in the same time), but the error persists. So what am I missing here? Thanks.